# Overwrite master with delete action from feature branch in GIT?

Tags: git, github

I've forked a feature branch named #ftr from master named #master. With time we commit in both separately. Now *how can i push everything from #ftr to #master with deletion of extra files in master and overwrite of all other files in master *

Note: action here is "overwrite master and delete extra files" and not "merge (or combine) with master with ours (for conflict)"

Comment: @JeffPuckettII: there is no `-s theirs`, only `-s ours`. (There is `-X theirs` as an argument to `-s recursive`, but that's not what is desired here.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is the equivalent of `-s theirs` (basically what Jeff Puckett II [suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851490/overwrite-master-with-delete-action-from-feature-branch-in-git#comment66990993_39851490)).  Unfortunately, this does not exist—but you can synthesize it easily enough.

#### The simple and obvious method

The slow and simple way, which is the most obvious, is to use `git merge` with `--no-commit`:

```
$ git checkout \#master
$ git merge --no-commit \#ftr # this may produce lots of conflicts
                              # but we don't care!
```

At this point, whether the merge is ready to go or has stopped with lots of conflicts, we simply *remove everything* from the work-tree and index:

```
$ git rm -r .                 # assumes you're in the top level
```

Now that you are about to commit the deletion of everything, we re-populate the index and work-tree from the commit you want to keep, which is the version that `#ftr` points-to:

```
$ git checkout \#ftr -- .
```

(Note that this is using the "check out some files" form of `git checkout`, not the "switch to another branch" form.)

Now the merge is ready to be concluded:

```
$ git commit
```

The result is a merge commit, made on the current (`#master`) branch, whose contents are the tree from the `#ftr` branch, and whose parents are the previous tip of `#master` (first parent) and current tip of `#ftr` (second parent).

#### The fast method

The fast method uses the fact that the *tree* for the new merge commit is simply the current existing tree for the tip of `#ftr`.  All we need to do is make a new commit that has two parents—the tip of `#master` and the tip of `#ftr`, in that order—and that has as its tree, the tree for the tip of `#ftr`.

The plumbing command `git commit-tree` can do this.  It's not the easiest command to use: first you should prepare your commit message, probably in a file, and then you can run:

```
$ newid=$(git commit-tree -F /tmp/mergemsg -p \#master -p \#ftr \#ftr^{tree})
```

This creates the commit object and store it in your repository.  The two `-p` flags set the parent IDs and the `#ftr^{tree}` argument sets the tree, while the commit message comes from the `/tmp/mergemsg` file.  You now, however, need to alter your `#master` branch to point to the new commit ID.  The easiest way to do that is to check out `#master` and use `git merge --ff-only` to fast-forward to the new commit:

```
$ git checkout \#master && git merge --ff-only $newid
```

Answer (score 0):

As torek pointed out in his answer, `-s theirs` does not exist, but there is `-s ours` which could be used on a temporary branch like this:

- `git checkout \#ftr`
- `git checkout -b master-to-be`
  make master-to-be point to where #ftr points, too
- `git merge -s ours \#master` merge master into master-to-be but only use #ftr
- `git checkout -B \#master` move #master branch to the new tip
- `git branch -d master-to-be` temporary branch is not needed anymore

Comment: This will run merge action (combine files) from 'master-to-be' to #master, am looking for  'overwrite master and delete extra files with no merge'

Comment: This is exactly what  `git merge -s ours #master` does. It discards everything which was previously in #master but maintains a clean history. Thus you could have an (old) repository which still has the #master branch you want to get rid of but has `origin` pointing to the construct above, do a `git pull` in there and you would have cleanly adopted all the changes you wanted. You wouldn't have to resolve any conflict with this way. Oh, and the merge command doesn't merge master-to-be into #master, it merges the other way round. `-s ours` says "discard everything coming from #master